# Find the largest index of the largest element in an array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, input

I have an array generated with random integers from 0 to 9, I have a function that does that. I also have a function that determines what the largest element from the array is. I need to write another function that determine the index of the largest variable. I believe the problem is that I cannot call the function within the function but it could be something else.

The code I have is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h> 

using namespace std;

void initialize(int arr[], int size);

void print(int arr[], int size);

void findLargest(int arr[], int size);

void largestIndex(int arr[], int size);


int main(){


    const int SIZE = 10;
    int myList[SIZE];

    initialize(myList, SIZE);

    print(myList, SIZE);

    findLargest(myList, SIZE);


    largestIndex(myList, SIZE);
    
    return 0;

}


void initialize(int arr[], int size){
    
    srand(time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        arr[i] = (rand() % 10);
     }
}
 

void print(int arr[], int size){
       for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        
        cout<<arr[j]<< endl;
    }
}


void findLargest(int arr[], int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

       if(arr[0] < arr[i])
           arr[0] = arr[i];
    }
    cout << "The largest element in the array is " << arr[0]<< endl;;
}


void largestIndex(int arr[], int size){

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(arr[i] == 9){
            cout<< "The index of the largest element is " + i <<endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can call functions within functions. That's not the problem. You shouldn't include `ctime` and `time.h`.

Comment: What is the question? :/

Comment: The root of the problem is that your functions print their findings to the terminal instead of returning the relevant values to the caller.

Comment: `findLargest` is "wrong", as it mutates the array.

Answer (score 1):

Ran it through compiler explorer

https://godbolt.org/z/c9ETjaq3z

Revealing this error message

```sh
<source>:69:59: warning: adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string [-Wstring-plus-int]
            cout<< "The index of the largest element is " + i <<endl;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
<source>:69:59: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
            cout<< "The index of the largest element is " + i <<endl;
                                                          ^
                   &                                      [  ]
```

This line

```cpp
 cout << "The index of the largest element is " + i <<endl;
```

Adds `i`  to the pointer to the character string `"The index of the largest element is "`. The result is that you carve of the beginning of the string instead of showing the value of i.

What you want is

```cpp
 cout << "The index of the largest element is " << i <<endl;
```

or

```cpp
 cout << "The index of the largest element is " + std::to_string(i) <<endl;
```

You might want to consider using [std::max_element](http://std::max_element)

```cpp
auto largest = *std::max_element(arr, arr + size);
std::cout << "Largest... = " << largest << std::endl;
```